# magento2, create correctly SELECT used collection

Tags: magento2, collection, select

i have this code

```
$collection = $this->orderCollectionFactory->create()
                ->addFieldToSelect(['increment_id', 'global_currency_code', 'status', 'updated_at', 'total_due', 'billingTable.vat_id'])
                ->addAttributeToFilter('status', ['in' => [
                    Order::STATE_CLOSED,
                    Order::STATE_COMPLETE,
                    Order::STATE_CANCELED,
                ]])
                ->addAttributeToFilter('created_at', ['from' => $result['from'], 'to' => $result['to']]);
            $collection->getSelect()->joinLeft(['billingTable' => 'sales_order_address'], "main_table.entity_id = billingTable.parent_id AND billingTable.address_type = '{$this->addressType}'");
```

i have this SQL

```
main_table.billingTable.vat_id' in 'field list', query was: SELECT `main_table`.`entity_id`, `main_table`.`increment_id`, `main_table`.`global_currency_code`, `main_table`.`status`, `main_table`.`updated_at`, `main_table`.`total_due`, `main_table`.`billingTable.vat_id`, `billingTable`.* FROM `sales_order` AS `main_table`\n LEFT JOIN `sales_order_address` AS `billingTable` ON main_table.entity_id = billingTable.parent_id AND billingTable.address_type = 'billing' WHERE (`status` IN('closed', 'complete', 'canceled')) AND (`created_at` >= '2020-05-15 12:00:00' AND `created_at` <= '2020-08-29 12:00:00')
```

i have problem with this `main_table.billingTable.vat_id`

i need `billingTable.vat_id`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try following :

- Remove `billingTable.vat_id` from `->addFieldToSelect(` instruction
- After this, replace :

```
$collection->getSelect()->joinLeft(['billingTable' => 'sales_order_address'], "main_table.entity_id = billingTable.parent_id AND billingTable.address_type = '{$this->addressType}'");
```

by

```
$collection->getSelect()->joinLeft(
    ['billingTable' => 'sales_order_address'], 
    "main_table.entity_id = billingTable.parent_id AND billingTable.address_type = '{$this->addressType}'",
    ['vat_id']
);
```